# `getchar()` gives the same output as the input string

Tags: c, eof, getchar

I am confused by a program mentioned in K&R that uses `getchar()`. It gives the same output as the input string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while(c != EOF){
         putchar(c);
         c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Why does it print the whole string? I would expect it to read a character and ask again for the input.

And, are all strings we enter terminated by an EOF?

Comment: Isnt EOF a char value and not an int?

Comment: I think it is an int whose value is -1.

Comment: Strings are terminated by \0.Files are terminated by EOF which is -1

Comment: I opened up a text file, but I didn't see an EOF at the end of it. :) Regardless, one could come up with an implementation of C where EOF is -42 if they wanted to... it doesn't matter what EOF is defined as in terms of a value. You should always use the constant.

Comment: @Fahad: files are terminated naturally at their end, not by the existence of a specific value at a specific position in the file. And EOF's value is whatever the implementation wants (usually -1; but **always EOF**)

Comment: Additional to this, which i recently figured out, is that it prints the whole string as putchar() doesn't add a new line after each character, in a similar way happens when you use multiple printf() without the '\n', everything gets in the same line, we think it just printed the whole line because it was able to read it at once, but is not because that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the simple setup you are likely using, `getchar` works with *buffered* input, so you have to press enter before getchar gets anything to read. Strings are not terminated by `EOF`; in fact, `EOF` is not really a character, but a magic value that indicates the end of the file. But `EOF` is not part of the string read. It's what `getchar` returns when there is nothing left to read.

Comment: When I tried the count char program in K&R, I found that `get char()` gets my input like "abc", when counting, it would be `4` instead of `3`, so I used `gdb` to debug it, it turned out that the additional one 'character' is (nl), whose ascii code is 0x0a. So, was my input a string? Wasn't that string are terminated by '\0'? Why was there a (nl)?

Comment: That's because the line feed character that terminates the line is part of the input. C is like that, deal with it.

Answer (score 32):

There is an underlying buffer/stream that `getchar()` and friends read from. When you enter text, the text is stored in a buffer somewhere. `getchar()` can stream through it one character at a time. Each read returns the next character until it reaches the end of the buffer. The reason it's not asking you for subsequent characters is that it can fetch the next one from the buffer.

If you run your script and type directly into it, it will continue to prompt you for input until you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (end of file). If you call it like `./program < myInput` where `myInput` is a text file with some data, it will get the `EOF` when it reaches the end of the input. `EOF` isn't a character that exists in the stream, but a sentinel value to indicate when the end of the input has been reached.

As an extra warning, I believe `getchar()` will also return `EOF` if it encounters an error, so you'll want to check `ferror()`. Example below (not tested, but you get the idea).

```
main() {
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF && ferror()) {
            perror("getchar");
        }
        else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    while(c != EOF);
}
```

Comment: Does 'bash' create the buffer or does Linux? Seems odd that K&R didn't mention this issue especially since they were Unix based. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Strings, by `C` definition, are terminated by `'\0'`. You have no `"C strings"` in your program.

Your program reads characters (buffered till ENTER) from the standard input (the keyboard) and writes them back to the standard output (the screen). It does this no matter how many characters you type or for how long you do this.

To stop the program you have to indicate that the standard input has no more data **(huh?? how can a keyboard have no more data?)**.

You simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Unix) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (Windows) to pretend the file has reached its end.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) are not really characters in the `C` sense of the word.

*If you run your program with input redirection, the `EOF` is the actual end of file, not a make belief one*
*`./a.out < source.c`*

Answer (score 3):

`getchar()` reads a single character of input and returns that character as the value of the function. If there is an error reading the character, or if the end of input is reached, `getchar()` returns a special value, represented by `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition of `getchar()`, it reads a character from the standard input. Unfortunately `stdin` is mistaken for keyboard which might not be the case for `getchar`. `getchar` uses a buffer as `stdin` and reads a single character at a time. In your case since there is no `EOF`, the `getchar` and `putchar` are running multiple times and it looks to you as it the whole string is being printed out at a time. Make a small change and you will understand:

```
putchar(c);
printf("\n");     
c = getchar();
```

Now look at the output compared to the original code.

Another example that will explain you the concept of `getchar` and buffered `stdin` :

```
void main(){
int c;
printf("Enter character");
c = getchar();
putchar();
c = getchar();
putchar();
}
```

Enter two characters in the first case. The second time when `getchar` is running are you entering any character? NO but still `putchar` works.

This ultimately means there is a buffer and when ever you are typing something and click enter this goes and settles in the buffer. `getchar` uses this buffer as `stdin`.