# Does this character counting program include the newline character?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 2nd version */
main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;

    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

When I compile and run the program and type in a character (example: abcd), hit enter, then hit the escape character CTRL+Z, it says 5. Is that because of the "hidden" newline character or does it count the EOF command? Because when I type the EOF command alone it stays as 0.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, given that you get 0 when you do only EOF. As a test, why not enter 3 lines of text then an EOF just to be sure?

Comment: Alright, I see now. I just want to be 100% sure of all of the programs/exercises before I move on. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you count in `double`?

Comment: That was just used as an example in the K&R C book.

Comment: Please make sure to *copy* code, not type it in. Proof: `gechar`

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I actually did copy and it seems it was wrong in the listed example. I'll be sure to check again next time.

Comment: What OS are you using System/360 or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

`getchar` waits for you to enter "something"; and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is 'something' (that is, it has a defined character value; other keys, <kbd>Shift</kbd> for example, may not).

By that same token, the key combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> would be "something" as well -- the value `26` on most systems -- but the standard input/output library you are using treats this particular code as a special command: `EOF`. On my OS, Mac OSX, that would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (for reasons unknown to me, other than "historically, Ctrl+D is used to signal EOF on Unix-like systems").

The 'newline character' is by no means "hidden" or "invisible", it's just another number that gets read and stored into a variable or string if you instruct it to do so. The reason you cannot see it is because `putchar` and other text printing functions do something else than "display the associated character": it moves the cursor to the next line. That also is part of the standard functionality, and a good thing it is too. After all you wouldn't want to press <kbd>Space</kbd> to "move to the next line". (In fact it's such a common function of this code that most fonts don't even bother to have a displayable item for it.)

See also [What does getchar() exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676796/what-does-getchar-exactly-do) for more background information.