# if I were to use the getchar() function and enter two characters, where does the second character get stored?

Tags: c, memory, getchar

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char c;
   c = getchar(); // Let's say you enter AA
   printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

Does the second character get stuck in some reserve spot in memory like the stack? Because I know if I were to added another c = getchar(), the second character would be assigned to the variable c.

Comment: Did you have a look at - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676796/what-does-getchar-exactly-do

Answer (score 4):

> Does the second character get stuck in some reserve spot in memory like the stack?

It is most likely in a buffer associated with `stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `AA` for a single character the remaining input will still be in the `stdin` buffer, as this program demonstrates. Instead of printing the characters, it prints their ASCII value for clarity. I entered `AA<Enter>` just once.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    c = getchar(); // Let's say you enter AA<Enter>
    printf("%d\n", c);

    c = getchar(); // still another A to come
    printf("%d\n", c);

    c = getchar(); // still a newline to come
    printf("%d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Program session

```
AA
65
65
10
```

Answer (score 0):

as you know getchar only take one variable.so the 2nd 'A' will not store any where.it will be on ROM for sometime but the moment you hit enter it will vanish.

Comment: `getchar(3)` doesn't "take" variables, and doesn't store anything in ROM of all places.