# C function, reverse string

Tags: c, function

I want help regarding a function which you call from main that reverse text. However, the program works, well "more or less" but it crashes. Here is how code looks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char * array, int numberOfChars) {
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
    char temp;

    end = strlen(&array) - 1;
    printf("%s", &array);

    while (begin < end) {
        temp = array[begin];
        array[begin] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;
        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}

int main() {
    reverse('supm', 4);
    return(0);
    getchar();
}
```

The string gets reversed to mpus, but then crashes, apparently it seems also like the arrays can only take in 4 characters, if i change it to 5 and the integer value to 5, it won't work at all.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all you can't have functions after `return`. Secondly, if you say it crashes, please post an error message.

Comment: That code should give you plenty of compiler warnings/errors. If not, check your compiler warning settings.

Comment: Almost *everything* is wrong, I suggest you work through a few C primers before attempting this.

Answer (score 5):

`strlen(&array)` and `printf("%s", &array);` are wrong. They will pass where **the pointer** is instead of where **the string** is. use `strlen(array)` and `printf("%s", array);`.

`reverse('supm', 4);` is also wrong because the first argument of this call is not a string but an implementation-defined integer.

Be careful that just changing it to `reverse("supm", 4);` won't work because modifying string literals isn't allowed.

Also, the last `getchar();` won't be executed because it is after `return 0;`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char * array, int numberOfChars) {
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
    char temp;

    end = strlen(array) - 1;
    printf("%s", array);

    while (begin < end) {
        temp = array[begin];
        array[begin] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;
        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}

int main() {
    char supm[] = "supm";
    reverse(supm, 4);
    puts(supm); /* added this to see if this code is working well */
    return(0);
}
```

Maybe you should use the parameter `numberOfChars` instead of `strlen(array)` because you pass the parameter, but it is not used at all.

Comment: I understand what you've done, but i just want to call the function from main, and what i mean by that is that i want to input "reverse('string', characters) without having to use char[supm] = "supm"  if you know what i mean.

Comment: @Philly you shouldn't use `'string'` because it is implementation-defined and it may cause overflow if your size of `int` is 32 bits. Use `"string"` (string literal) instead of `'string'` (character constant), then just print and don't do the modification because you don't print the reversed string in the function, and you cannot pass the reversed string to the caller in this case unless the second parameter `characters` is a pointer or an array.

Answer (score 3):

A few things immediately pop out at me:

1. strlen should take a `char*`, where you are passing a `char**`. Instead of `strlen(&array)`, use `strlen(array)`.
2. Similar story with `printf`. Instead of `printf("%s", &array)`, use `printf("%s", array)`.
3. Your string literal in main incorrectly uses single quotes, when it should be using double quotes. Your `'supm'` should be `"supm"`. You also cannot modify a string literal, so you'll need to set a variable containing your string and then pass the variable instead.
4. You `return(0)` before calling `getchar`. That means `getchar` will never be called.
5. `numberOfChars` is unused. Either remove that parameter or use it instead of `strlen`.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `reverse` -

```
end = strlen(&array) - 1;
printf("%s", &array);
```

You pass `char **` to `strlen` which expects a `const char *`  and try to print a `char **` with `%s` . Jusr pass `array` to both these functions. 
And in `main` -

```
reverse('supm', 4);
```

If you even do `"spum"` which would be string literal , thus constant (modifying it would cause problem).

Do this instead -

```
char s[]="spum"; 
reverse(s, 4);
```

*Compiler must have issued warnings for these statements and if not then enable compiler warnings.*

Comment: What if, in the function at the start you say `char s[] = array`, and then worked off of `s`? would this allow you to pass a string literal?

Comment: @Adjit No. it wouldn't. It will emit [compile error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QYTNDrdzqE78HtgC).

Comment: @Adjit I guess than you would need to use `strcpy` for that to work . You cannot assign values to arrays just you do to variables .

Comment: @Adjit Copying string literal to such array will work . **Note** - Not passing `"spum"` directly .

Comment: How would you use `strcpy`? Just pass the return value to the function? `reverse(strcpy("spum"), 4)`

Comment: @Adjit `strcpy` inside function  .

Answer (score 1):

1. `array`is already a pointer-- `&array`gives you a pointer to the pointer. so change the strlen call to this:

   ```
   strlen(array);
   ```
2. you need to define the string before you pass to the function-- otherwise the string only exists inside your function, you won't be able to access it outside.

   ```
   char mystr[] = "supm";
   reverse(mystr, 4);
   printf("%s\n", mystr);
   return 0;
   ```

Comment: Do not remove the -1 because `array[strlen(array)]` is the null character, which you won't want.

Comment: @ameyCU If `char array[]="spum";` `array[0]='S'`, `array[1]='p'`, `array[2]='u'`, `array[3]='m'`, `array[4]='\0'`. so the trouble will happen.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes , realized that it was inside `[]` , therefore , removed my comment earlier.

Comment: Ah yes you're right-- I was mistakenly thinking OP wanted the string length. It seems he actually wants index of last readable char, so yes this would cause an issue! Have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code I have fixed all your code problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char * array, int numberOfChars) {
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
    char temp;

    end = strlen(array) - 1;
    printf("%s\n", array);

    while (begin < end) {
        temp = array[begin];
        array[begin] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;
        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[] ="sump";
    reverse(str, 4);
    puts(str);    
    return(0);
    
}
```

What you can learn from problems of this code ?

> void reverse(char * array, int numberOfChars) /* definition */
>
> reverse('supm', 4); /*calling function */

Compare this both two in definition first argument is to pass character array `char *array` But in calling you are passing`'sump'` .Now onwards please remember for more than character you can use `""` so here you should use `"sump"`

> end = strlen(&array) - 1;

Refer [strlen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen)

Its argument is constant character pointer . But here you are passing `&array` .I guess you think `&array` is address of array but that is wrong for array `array` represent address and `array[i]` represent value

> getchar()

This function is for reading input not for printing strings.
refer [getchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676796/what-does-getchar-exactly-do)

For printing reversed output you should use [puts](http://linux.die.net/man/3/puts) at last not `getchar`

Comment: Did you mean to post some modified code? Because you actually posted the original code!

Comment: As I see questioner is beginner in c I have just gave him similar working code and show him where he did mistakes so he can understand `c` and do not repeat same mistakes next time.

Comment: You've changed it now, but your changed code still has the incorrect `strlen(&array)` from the original code.

Comment: Sorry @IanAbbott I have mistakenly paste wrong code instead of my compiled one. Thanks for suggestion .I have updated the answer .

Comment: Thanks. That's more like it!

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function, the line `reverse('supm', 4);` has a couple of things wrong with it. First of all, it is a character constant, not a string, so you will end up passing an invalid pointer value to your `reverse` function. You probably meant to use `"supm"` which is a string and does match the `char *` expected by your `reverse` function. However, `"supm"` is a string literal constant, so although you can point to it, you are not allowed to modify it. So you should do something like this:

```
    char rev[] = "supm";
    reverse(rev, 4);
```

Here, `rev` is an array of 5 `char`, initialized as `{'s', 'u', 'p', 'm', '\0'}`.

You are not currently using the `numberOfChars` parameter of `reverse`, so you could remove it.