# odd behaviour of getchar() function

Tags: c, getchar

I'm trying to write a function which stores data in a text file, using the `fopen("filename","w")` where "filename" is a string inputted by the user.  I've chosen to do so via the `getchar()` function and I need a counter variable that is being incremented with every keystroke. Here is where things get convoluted and confusing.

```
   char *p;
   int count = 0; 
   p = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char));
   do 
   {
       *p = getchar();
       count++;
   }
   while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Up until 3 characters inputted it needs only 1 press of the Enter key and the counter is accurate until 2 characters after 2 it follows an odd pattern.

```
--------------------Input------------------------Count--------------------
-------------------- t --------------------------  1  --------------------
-------------------- te -------------------------  2  --------------------
-------------------- tes  -----------------------  2  --------------------
-------------------- test ------------------------ 3 ---------------------
-------------------- test1 ----------------------- 3 ---------------------
-------------------- test12 ---------------------- 4 ---------------------
-------------------- test123 --------------------- 4 ---------------------
-------------------- test1234 -------------------- 5 ---------------------
```

Basically, for every 2 additional chars, the count gets incremented by one.

How does the function works in this context and why does it need 2 keystrokes?

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And `sizeof(char)` is defined to yield `1`. It is superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave Schwartz is right about calling getchar() twice.  There are one or two more rough edges in your code fragment; let's talk about those while I expand a little bit on Dave's answer.

The C language can be VERY dense; multiple things can be going on in a single line of code.  For someone just starting out, I would encourage you to write things long form, even if you don't think you need to... then consolidate as your mental model of what C is doing becomes richer.

For example... let's revise your code fragment to look like this:

```
int count = 0; 
p = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char));
char c = getchar(); /* first call to getchar() */
while( c != '\n') {
   p[count] = c; /* easier to read than *p=getchar() */
   count++; /* could be combined...  see below for a more C-like version. */
   /* question: what would happen if we increment count BEFORE we store in p's memory? */

   /* Also... your initial code was this: */
   /*   *p = getchar(); */
   /* which is always assigning getchar to p[0]. */
   /* see below for more "idiomatic" way to do that. */
   /* see below for more "idiomatic" way to do that. */

   /* Get the next char, then let while() condition decide if */
   /* we come back into the loop body or proceed after it. */
   /* It is a common tactic to put an input value in a scratch variable */
   /* like 'c' and use it at different points in your loop. */

   c = getchar(); /* all additional calls to getchar. */
   /* note that we already declared c above the while-loop, so ok to re-use. */
}
/* dont want to call getchar() again here... this is the problem dave called out. */
/* while( getchar() != '\n' ); */
/* ...do some stuff here */
free(p); /* your logic does free the malloc at some point, yes? :-) */
```

Now you *could* try collapse as much code into a single expression as possible.
But *please* don't do that - at least not until you can comfortably write code that is 1) easy to read, and 2) easy to predict what it will do.

You will eventually find *writing* code isn't the hard part.

It is *reading* code that was written 2 weeks (or 2+ years ago) that is hard.

Let's talk about looping next: while(), for() and do/while() to work with.
The while() and for() give you the option to skip the loop body... the do/while() will Always execute the loop body, which may not be what you want in your situation since they user could just hit enter giving you the first character as '\n'.

**for loop version**
Consider how your logic might look usuing a  for() loop:

```
int count = 0; 
p = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char));
for( char c = getchar(); c != '\n'; c = getchar() ) {
   p[count] = c;
   count++;
}
```

**do/while version**
I find it more difficult to write this with a do/while() loop:
Not that it is hard to *write* the code, but I find it hard to make the code readable so the *intent* is clear.

```
int count = 0; 
p = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char));
char c;
do {
   if( count >= 1  ) {
      /* ugly... check count >= 1 so we don't save an uninitialized 'c' */
      p[count] = c;
   }
   count++;
} while( (c = getchar() );
count--; /* adjust because we counted our '\n'. */
```

**again with some extra C idioms**
This one is hard to read because to understand it you have to be able
to untangle the while() expression, which does the following things:

1) calls the getchar() function and assigns the result to our temp var 'c'

2) compares the result of that assignment to '\n'

3) while() evaluates the result of the compare and only enters the loop body if we have something besides a '\n' in temp char var 'c'.

That is a lot to wrap your head around before you can ask "was it true?".
fyi - this is the only sample I actually tried to run...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void main( char **argv ) {
   printf("Please type some stuff:\n");

    int count = 0; 
    char *p = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char));
    char c;
    while( (c = getchar() ) != '\n') {
       p[count++] = c;
       /* So... could we just saying the following instead?
        *     *p++ = c;
        */
    }
    p[count] = '\0'; /* this would turn our malloced buffer into a C-style string */
    printf("found %d chars = '%s'\n", count, p);
    free(p);
}
```

For one last point to ponder, consider the following:

1) Is there a limit to how many characters our user can type before they hit enter?

2) Assuming #1 does have a limit, what is it and *why*?

3) What could you do to add a check to ensure we don't let our user try to type too many characters?

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;`  , and you should also check it is not `EOF`

Comment: wow man, I'm flabbergasted by your response. Thank you, I appreciate your time and effort.It looks like this site has a great community, I'm loving it.Thank you again you were very helpful and I wish you happy holidays :).

Comment: @M.M agreed... better to use 'int c' vs. 'char c'.  Also better to check for getchar() returning -1 to indicate eof.  Also better to check for malloc failure. :-)  After Paragon is further along on the learning they can read up on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676796/what-does-getchar-exactly-do

Comment: Paragon - I appreciate the thanks.  Programming can be a lot of fun.  C has some surprising complexity in it, I'll encourage you to try running the program and type in 100 random characters (more or less).  For me it core dumped, it will be useful for you to work through why.  Also M.M raises a good point, but I wouldn't worry too much about stuff like that for initial classroom / research code. Have fun :-)

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And `sizeof(char)` is defined to yield `1`. It is superfluous.

Answer (score 6):

You call `getchar` twice each time in the loop. You push enter (newline) at the end of the characters. And you bump the count *before* the second `getchar`. So the count will be `(n + 1) / 2` rounded up, where `n` is the number of characters.

Plus one for the newline. Divided by two because two characters are read for each increment. And rounded up because the increment occurs before the second read.