# scanf is skipped (?)

Tags: c

I tried to do a small Worker Register, but it skips completely the second scanf, which gets address value. I am a beginner, so I do not know what I am doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // var
    char n[256], ad[256]; // n - Name, ad - Address
    int i, ag; // i - Income, ag - Age
    // code
    printf("Welcome to the Worker Register\n\nWorker Data\n\nName: ");
    scanf("%255[^\n]", n);
    printf("Address: ");
    scanf("%255[^\n]", ad);
    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &ag);
    printf("Income: R$");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Worker %s\nAddress: %s\nAge: %d\nIncome: R$%d", n, ad, ag, i);
    return 0;
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nad's hack of adding a getchar() seems to fix it, but I wouldn't use scanf for reading strings if I were you.

It's nicer to use fgets() reading strings instead.  scanf on a string is problematic.  See:  [Reading a string with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

e.g.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 ...
 printf("Welcome to the Worker Register\n\nWorker Data\n\nName: ");
 fgets(n, 256, stdin);
 ...
```

Regarding the size parameter in `fgets()`.  The man page states:

> fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
>   and
>          stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading  stops  after  an
>          EOF  or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
>          A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the  last  character  in
>          the buffer.

Therefore you enter the size of the buffer and ignore the null byte as fgets will do that work for you.

Comment: Yes, I read that thread and some threads like it, but I am in the beginning of my C course, so I do not even know what is a pointer. I tried learning it, but I couldn't understand it very well, so I will put aside for now and when I study it I will come back. Thank you!                                                                  @Edit: fgets is from what library?

Comment: `fgets()` is in the same library as `scanf()`.

Comment: Regarding about buffer overflow, shouldn't I put "fgets(n, 255, stdin);" instead of "fgets(n, 256, stdin);"?

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add a   getchar(); To be honest, I don't know why but this has happened to me plenty of times in school. It seemed to fix it :)

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    // var
    char n[256], ad[256]; // n - Name, ad - Address
    int i, ag; // i - Income, ag - Age
               // code
    printf("Welcome to the Worker Register\n\nWorker Data\n\nName: ");
    scanf("%255[^\n]", n);
    printf("Address: ");
    getchar();
    scanf("%255[^\n]", ad);
    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &ag);
    printf("Income: R$");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Worker %s\nAddress: %s\nAge: %d\nIncome: R$%d", n, ad, ag, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What getchar() really do? @Edit: What library I need to put to use it?

Comment: It might be kind to explain why you don't need a `getchar()` after reading `ad` — you're right, you don't absolutely need it, but it isn't immediately obvious why not.  Were it my code, it would be there for reasons of symmetry.  You should probably also check that `scanf()` works rather than just assuming that it does.

Comment: Not sure but you can read more [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676796/what-does-getchar-exactly-do)**Here**

Comment: I read that thread already but I think it speaks of a special case.

Comment: If the first character is `'\n'` for `scanf("%255[^\n]", n);` leads to trouble - UB.  Checking the return value of `scanf()` is good programming.

Answer (score 0):

`"%255[^\n]"` meant input up to newline(accepts inputs other than newline).(The newline isn't included.)
So, there is a newline in the input buffer(of stdin),
second scanf (`scanf("%255[^\n]", ad);` ) also accepts inputs other than newline,
So, It will not be entered.

Therefore you need to consume the newline in first scanf.
E.g `scanf("%255[^\n]%*c", n);` `%*c` ignores one character(That is the newline).

Since `%d` of 3rd scanf skips the previous white-spaces, `%*c` isn't necessary for 2nd scanf.